# Superconductors vs Ideal conductors

Tags: ohms-law, superconductors

I have always assumed superconductors and ideal conductors as the same thing, but recently I found out that they are not.

I tried to look up their differences on the internet, but I got only mixed up explanations.

Can someone tell me their key differences and similarities with proper definitions? (Because the one that I found on the internet were rather similar)

Also, do the ideal conductors follow Ohm's law? I have a feeling that they should but since they have R=0 ,I don't know if that will workout well.

Comment: You can go and see a super conductor (if they let you in) but an ideal conductor is a concept.

Comment: @SolarMike Superconductors from a material standpoint isnt always something rare. Aluminum and lead are superconductors. Its the temperature thats the hard part. But I imagine Aluminum looks pretty similar at 300 K and at 1 K. Im not sure who has to "let you in"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An Ideal Conductor is a theoretical construct, available only in simulators and theory. It has zero resistance, zero inductance, zero capacitance to ground, can carry an infinite current, can support an infinite voltage difference to any adjacent conductors, and has zero electrical length.

An ordinary copper wire approximates those features, more or less well, depending on length, cross section, purity, insulation material round it.

A superconductor has zero resistance, and approximates the rest of those features, more or less well, depending again on its physical characteristics.

Comment: About infinite voltage ,I am a bit confused.An ideal conductor isn't supposed to have any electric field inside it.I was of the idea that once the electric field i.e voltage is applied to the ideal conductor the current starts to flow and remains so even if the voltage turns to zero.Can you plz tell where have I gone wrong?

Comment: @mia I'll update my answer to reword it slightly. The voltage is with respect to adjacent nodes. The voltage everywhere within the conductor is the same, that is, there's a zero voltage difference between any two parts of the ideal conductor.

Comment: @mia It's ok to say that the potential is same **and** the potential difference is zero, `but` is wrong. I'm not going to get drawn into a pedantic argument about voltage or potential. Both are measured in volts, and when scaled by charge, both mean energy. It's totally obvious from the context in which each is used what it means, and lazy people like me use both interchangeably. I have heard a physicist saying that one is used for energy, and the other for work, but I can't remember which, and frankly don't care.

Comment: No, I didnot mean to offend you or something.I actually asked it as a question as my understanding is still introductory and I thought I was wrong.Sorry for my poor English -- it is not my first language and I highly respect the answer you gave to me.I understand a lot.Thank you so much.

Answer (score 2):

You can even make an "artificial superconductor" by inserting a variable voltage source adding a voltage V = I.R in the circuit (R is the line resistance). It will act as a negative resistor with resistance -R that neutralizes the positive line resistance R; the result will be zero line resistance. Of course, this is paid for with extra energy. The well-known circuit of a transimpedance amplifier does this magic...